# for loop to concatenate strings

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need to concatenate strings in the list and add the integers to a sum; of course, I intend to change it to other data types later - thanks so much for all your kind responses

```
l = ['magical unicorns', 19, 'hello', 98.98, 'world']

comb_str = ''
comb_int = 0

for i in l:
    if type(i) is 'str':
        comb_str = comb_str + 'i'
    elif type(i) is 'int':
        comb_int += i
    else:
        pass

print comb_str
print comb_int
```

I am just getting the '0' output that was initialized in the beginning as if it skipped over the for loop :)

Comment: Please put your code in a code section.  (You can do this with the <> button after highlighting your code or by making sure every line starts with 4 spaces.)  Please also provide the current output.

Comment: Use `for i in range(0,len(l))` to iterate over the list. Use the modulo (`%`) to determine if `i` is divisible by 2 - if so, `comb_str += l[i]`, if not, do the same for `comb_int`.

Comment: Use a `for` loop. Check the type of the element. If it's a string, concatenate it to `comb_str`. If it's an integer, add it to `comb_int`.

Comment: The code is probably working perfectly. It initializes 3 variables. You haven't shown us any code that tries to concatenate strings or sum numbers, nor have you explained *how* it "isn't working"

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston The odd elements aren't all integers, there's also a float.

Comment: Thanks so much guys/gals! It is such a joy to see a fellow coder respond so promptly. I believe I follow now. Loren, Appreciate the feedback. First time posting, so still trying to figure out how things work. Tried to do some manual cleanup so that it would be more readable, obviously with little success. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your statements literally (that you only want integers, not numerics) the entire program comes down to two function calls with filtered versions of the list

```
>>> l = ['magical unicorns', 19, 'hello', 98.98, 'world']
>>> ''.join([s for s in l if isinstance(s,str)])
'magical unicornshelloworld'
>>> sum([i for i in l if isinstance(i,int)])
19
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
l = ['magical unicorns', 19, 'hello', 98.98, 'world']
l1 = [g for g in l if type(g)==int]
l2 = [g for g in l if type(g)==str]
print(sum(l1))
print(''.join(l2))
```

This will print your desired outcome.